# In Acobat, how can I enforce a minimum font size in a field with auto-font sizing, and multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, fonts, adobe, acrobat

I've found interesting solutions here about setting a font size on blur and focus; what I am looking to do is to limit how small a font can get as a user types more text into a field. Setting a character limit does not provide a reliable solution because line breaks can allow font to get extremely small long before any character limit is met.

Is there a way in Adobe Acrobat to, upon typing, have the font size decrease until a minimum of say 8pt, then prevent additional typing?

Answer (score 0):

In Acrobat, when a mulit-line text field has no text limit and is set to not scroll long text and the font size is set to auto, you have no control over the font size... by design. However, the minimum font size is 6. The font size will shrink to accommodate the amount of text entered until it hits 6 points and then prevent more text from being entered. There is no programmatic control. This happens live as you type. If you want something other than 6 as the minimum, you'll need to add some script. It can be done but the user experience is horrid because the text needs to be committed before the correct size can be calculated.